# Start firefox extension using folder

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-5

I'm new to Firefox extension development. I have gone through some basic [tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Creating_a_status_bar_extension). When I do as shown in the tutorial by placing the folder into profile folder/extensions folder, or in profile folder it made no change in the extension installation after restart. 
Then, I have gone through this [tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Building_an_Extension) as well. I tried using the pointer object also. This also not working for me. 
Firefox version I'm using is 14.0.1, 
And When I try to install ESPN Crickinfo (you could be able find extension on-line) extension, It also not working. I couldn't open the options page of this extension even.
Any suggestions on this problem???

Answer (score 0):

Try using a fresh profile http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles